# Use of comma with "of course"

Tags: grammar

When "of course" is at the end of a sentence, should a comma precede it?

Comment: I'm sure this answer exists on the internet.  Did you look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need a comma before an adverb as last word in sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319200/need-a-comma-before-an-adverb-as-last-word-in-sentence) Also [Use of comma before adverb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/547008/) and [Should there be a comma before “though” when it occurs at the end of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9125/) and [Comma before “now” at end of sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450348/) - and doubtless several more, ***in fact***.

Comment: Not as a matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No! It depends on the sentence. Here are some examples:

> We lose beloved public figures every year, of course.

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/07/sports/rafer-johnson-sports-deaths.html

> If this means just that she’s sympathetic to the problems women face and interested in how they deal with those problems, well then of course.

Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/18/books/the-wild-rangy-unclassifiable-delights-of-joy-williamss-fiction.html

Comment: Your second example requires a comma, of course.